# asp.net setting button command in code behind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I define a button like this:

```
            Button info = new Button();
            info.Command += Button_Command;
            info.CommandName = "handleinfoclick";
            info.CommandArgument = id;
```

And I tried to write a command handler here:

```
private void Button_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("HERE IN BUTTON COMMAND");
}
```

But the command handler is not being called. I have worked on this for a while and I haven't been able to find a solution. The button has to be defined in the codebehind because it is on a dynamic table and the function it calls will need the commandargument to interact with that row's data.

Comment: Is this web forms? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393543/how-to-create-an-asp-button-dynamically-and-add-event-to-it.

Comment: Where did you create the button? Could you show the event that `new Button()` code is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is web forms, then assigning server events dynamically will no work. I think the best approach is to assign events statically in your code and use some variables to define specific status. Then you can set the variables values and process them inside event and make decision to do some work.